# Is it possible to find the sign of an input number, with neural network?

Tags: neural-network

For example I have a set of numbers  {3 4 5 -6 -43 2 -7 8 5 -3 456 78 5}, and I want a NN program that categorises the positive and negative number of this set.

Is it possible for NN?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't really look like a problem for a NN, but more like an if-else statement.

But answering you question, yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a overly simplified question for a NN. You could probably simply use a linear classifier. Why are you trying to overkill the problem with a NN?

Comment: because i will solve much more complicated problem with NN. which involves bunch of, sign determinations. there will be 2^16 different configuration of signs of the inputs, and these configs will give in total 30 different outputs. so writing all of this with if and else, is actual overkill, I want my NN to learn a pattern.

Comment: So yes, you probably could very easily.